# puppeteer web scraping conditionals if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

Scraping a table... Each country name is within an `<a>` tag, but some are not. When the structure changes, the program crashes

Code =>

[image]

Output =>

[image]

I have tried doing the following

`const countryName = e.children[1].children[0].children[0].data || 'hello world'`

It does not work
But also I tried with an IfStatement

```
const countryName = e.children[1].children[0].children[0].data
if (countryName === undefined) {
   countryName = 'hello world'
}
```

It did not work either, same output error.

I know what does the error mean... I know that the HTML structure is not the same, but it won't read the conditionals that I'm implementing to give the `countryName` variable its value

Any ideas?

*PD: Same output with cheeriojs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
$(e).find('a').first().text() || 'hello world'
```

You almost never want to resort to using children with cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

You check for `undefined` too late: any `children` can be `undefined` and indexing this `undefined` with `[0]` can throw the error.

If your Node.js (V8) or transpiling supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), you can do this:

```js
const countryName = e?.children?.[1]?.children?.[0]?.children?.[0]?.data ?? 'hello world';
```

Otherwise, you need this:

```js
const countryName =
  e &&
  e.children &&
  e.children[1] &&
  e.children[1].children &&
  e.children[1].children[0] &&
  e.children[1].children[0].children &&
  e.children[1].children[0].children[0] &&
  e.children[1].children[0].children[0].data ||
  'hello world';
```